# How to make a complex SQL query with nested models?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models:
`Channel` > `Program` > `Episode`

```
Channel has_many programs
Program belongs_to channel
Program has_many episodes
Episode belongs_to program
```

How to make this query?

*** "Number of total `Episode`s of associated `Channel` which has the highest number of `Program`s. ***

To be more detailed,

1. Find the Channel which has the highest number of programs.
2. Find number of episodes joining with programs that belong to that Channel.

I'm really stucked.

How to do this most efficiently instead of writing lines of codes and many queries?

Comment: sql server,mysql,oracle?

Comment: @Mihai active record query is independent of databases right?

Comment: @emaillenin To be frank,I had no idea what active record is.

Comment: It's postgresql @Mihai. Any help with even with SQL appreciated.

Comment: So you want to find the total count of episodes for the channel with the greatest number of programs? What treatment do you want where there are many channels that all have the greatest number of programs, but presumably different numbers of episodes?

Comment: I just want to get the channel with the greatest number of programs in this case David. And then I want to get all of it's programs. And then I want to get all episodes of those programs.

Comment: I think this question is a really hard one?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to do with active record. But  you can solve this problem with sql,

for example

```
select top 1 c.channel_id, count(p.)  as count from Program as p inner join Channels as c on c.channel_id=p.channel_id group by  c.channel_id order by 2 desc
```